# How to go up a line to fix a mistake in command line? MySQL console

Tags: mysql

I really looked hard and long and is there really no way to go up a line to fix a typo without having to type my query all over again?

I am using MySQL console on Windows 7.

If not, what should I be using to learn MySQL?

Comment: 1. Don't make mistakes. Especially in windows console. 2. Install a local copy of [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php). It has more friendly means to execute a query. 3. For native clients, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows).

Comment: If you are going to use console, which is perfectly acceptable IMO, type your queries out in notepad (or preferably notepad++) first.

Comment: Thanks, I figured I could use phpMyAdmin, but the Oreilly Learn SQL book says to use MySQL Console so I figured why would it lie to me. Thx!

Comment: There are tons of good MySQL clients. When you're learning, make sure you have good example databases so don't get the wrong results and false positives.

Comment: the console is a harsh mistress. learn from it! although, i wouldn't recommend working like that in a production environment ;)

Comment: you should probably use linux :P

Comment: I'm actually enjoying learning from it because it does indeed force you to be accurate and I'm fine with that...(kinda)

Comment: Well, I have Cygwin installed and I use it for routine file searching/copying but how to use MySQL with Cygwin is not a task I have invested time into as of yet.

Comment: no, seriously install a real linux. it will be pain for 2-3 days (only if you don't know it yet) but later you won't look back unless you'll have to code something specifically for windows. and you will LOVE the terminal.

Answer (score 7):

Using `\e` will allow you to edit the command by opening it up in text editor

```
edit      (\e) Edit command with $EDITOR.
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html

Comment: Note that you can type `\e` at the end of a query and press Enter to edit that query in a text editor. Once in the text editor, remember to end your query with a semi-colon if you want it to run as soon as you close the text editor.

Answer (score -6):

just press the up arrow on your keyboard once or several times! it also works even if you let your queries span several rows :)

this is also good for repeating lines. the down arrow key can also be used, and as long as you don't modify a row, there is sort of a line pointer remembering what line you're on. so to execute lines 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 and 2, you type in the first 4 lines manually, then press up arrow 4 times, return, down arrow, and return again.

Comment: problem is it doesn't work like that. It should though.